# Field expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models, integer

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Quiz_Model(models.Model):
    quiz_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length = 30, default = '', blank = True)
    test_number = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    max_test_number = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    first_boundary = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    last_boundary = models.IntegerField(default = 1)
    show_number = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    tests = models.TextField()

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = '')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.last_boundary:
            self.last_boundary = self.max_test_number
        self.slug = slugify(self.quiz_name)
    
        super(Quiz_Model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


    def __str__ (self):
        return self.quiz_name
```

I keep gettings this error :TypeError: Field 'last_boundary' expected a number but got <django.db.models.fields.IntegerField>.

Comment: What version of Django and Python are you using? Cannot recreate this exception, could you provide code where you are creating instance of this model?

Comment: Share the full traceback togethe with the relevant view, form, template, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by defining values when creating the model:

```
quiz_instance = Quiz_Model(quiz_name = quiz_name, test_number = test_number, 
max_test_number = length, first_boundary = 1, last_boundary = length, show_number = 
show_number, tests = serialized_data, user = request.user)
quiz_instance .save()
```

However, I had to reset the database to prevent existing quizzes from causing problems.